# sizeToFit is placing padding around very short strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, uikit

I have a UIButton on which I call `sizeToFit` after settings its title. In cases where the title text is very short (probably < 20pt), the button is taking on a few points of padding on the left and right. For anything longer, the padding disappears. It is as if the button has an internal minimum width that is respected when `sizeToFit` is called. Does anyone know how to prevent this padding?

Comment: Please include a snippet of the code. Otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

This works, Just change the string to whatever and and enjoy the resizing miracle.

```
NSString * helloKitty = @"I love cats";
UIButton * ss = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[ss setTitle:helloKitty forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[ss titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
[ss setBackgroundColor:[UIColor pink] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGSize strSizer = [helloKitty sizeWithAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],
                                                 NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]}];

[ss setFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,strSizer.width, strSizer.height)];
[self.view addSubview:ss];
```